# (Rviz <-> point cloud from pcd) transformation

Tags: rviz, transforms, coordinate-system, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am reading in point clouds from *.pcd-files and am visualizing them using RViz. Unfortunately, the point cloud is weirdly oriented:

[Look here (the "right" side of the point cloud is actually the floor)](http://postimg.org/image/h2s0kag1h/)

I believe that this is because ROS uses a different coordinate system than PCL (or at least than how these pointclouds have been recorded). **How do I display my point cloud correctly?**

After reading through some tutorials I think I need to implement a tf-broadcaster that transforms between a "world" frame (ROS coordinate system) and a "pcd" frame (coordinate system used in my files). Then I can set the world-frame as fixed frame in Rviz and as a transformation for the PointCloud2 display my broadcasted transformation. Is that correct? Or is there a more elegant way of getting Rviz to display the point cloud "correctly"?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221964/(rviz-%3C-%3E-point-cloud-from-pcd)-transformation/) by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't want to use a static_transform_publisher you could use one of the `pcl_ros::transformPointCloud` functions either with a `tf::Transform` object representing the needed transformation or an `Eigen::Matrix4f` .

See [pcl_ros::transformPointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#ae730596163b8fa79f374faa0eae1c53f) or [pcl_ros::transformPointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#aad20af010640a41f1898e75f6a6121ad)

---

Originally posted by [sven-hoek](https://answers.ros.org/users/25252/sven-hoek/) with karma: 26 on 2015-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on 2015-12-07**:
I ended up using the static_transform_publisher, I did not know about that one yet :)